# how to retrieve a ssl certificate in django?

Tags: django, ssl-certificate, lighttpd

Is it possible to retrieve the client's SSL certificate from the current connection in Django?
I don't see the certificate in the request context passed from the lighttpd.
My setup has lighttpd and django working in fastcgi mode.
Currently, I am forced to manually connect back to the client's IP to verify the certificate..
Is there a clever technique to avoid this? Thanks!

Update:
I added these lines to my lighttpd.conf:

```
ssl.verifyclient.exportcert = "enable"
setenv.add-request-header = (
    "SSL_CLIENT_CERT" => env.SSL_CLIENT_CERT
)
```

Unfortunately, the env.SSL_CLIENT_CERT fails to dereference (does not exist?) and lighttpd fails to start.
If I replace the "env.SSL_CLIENT_CERT" with a static value like "1", it is successfully passed to django in the request.META fields.
Anything else, I could try? This is lighttpd 1.4.29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Though this question is not Django specific.

Usually web servers have option to export SSL client-side certificate data as environment variables or HTTP headers. I have done this myself with Apache (not Lighttpd).

This is how I did it

1. On Apache, export SSL certificate data to environment variables
2. Then, add a new HTTP request headers containing these environment variables
3. Read headers in Python code

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_SSL

Looks like the option name is `ssl.verifyclient.exportcert`.

Though I am not sure how to do step 2 with lighttpd, as I have little experience on it.

Comment: Thank you, Mikko! I did add the ssl.verifyclient.exportcert to the appropriate section of lighttpd.conf. Yet, I still do not get the cert in the request.META [or environ as I found in some other post[. I suspect lighttpd 1.2.29 does not furnish it correctly. This is an older version of lighttpd, but that's what I have to work with at this time.

Comment: The section of lighttpd.conf looks ~ this, if anybody would like to see it:
$SERVER["socket"] == "[::]:443" {
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.pemfile = "/path/cert.pem"
ssl.ca-file = "/path/cert.pem"
ssl.verifyclient.activate = "enable"
ssl.verifyclient.exportcert = "enable"
}